# Sharing Code and Classes between different .NET Platform (UWP, .Net Core)

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

A Trying to share some classes between the three layer of my application.

- Universal Windows Platform project (UWP on Raspberry Pi IoT)
- .NET Core Web Api project
- Asp.Net Core project

Witch project type should I use to share code and classes between those three project?
I'm planning to store DTOs object/interface and some Enums in these librairy.

I've try so far, without success
- .Net Standard 2
- UWP Class Library

Any idea?

Comment: What went wrong with .Net Standard?

Comment: I get this error, when refering from UWP  :  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1201 Project Garden.Common is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063) / win10-x64. Project Garden.Common supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) Garden.IoT C:\Projects\Garden\Garden.IoT\Garden.IoT.csproj 1

Comment: You need uwp sdk version 16299 or highter. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/10/announcing-uwp-support-for-net-standard-2-0/

Comment: Great that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has Kalten suggested, setting the target minimum version of the UWP version to "Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299) solved the problem.

Thanks Kalten!